# Search through name instead of id in code igniter..?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a new to php, have this code in controller:

```
public function selectquery($id){
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('aboutmodel');
    $data['h'] = $this->aboutmodel->selectquery($id);
    $this->load->view('aboutpageview', $data);
}
```

and this in model:

```
public function selectquery($id){
    $query =$this->db->get_where('phone_mobileinfos',array('id'=>$id));
    // return $query->row_array();
    return $query;
}
```

this in view:

{

```
<p>Mobile_name:<?php echo $h['mobile_name'];?></p>

<p>Price:<?php echo $h['price'];?></p>
```

}
Just want to search by name instead of id any suggestions..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - We're here to help, not to code for you. Show us what you've tried so far and we'll help you. But we're not ready to provide you solutions without you showing any effort. Just look at the code and try it, its kinda easy.

Answer (score 1):

In model:

```
public function selectByName($name){
    $query =$this->db->get_where('phone_mobileinfos',array('name'=>$name));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

use in controller:

```
$data['by_name'] = $this->aboutmodel->selectquery($id);
```

in view:

```
<p>Mobile_name:<?php echo $by_name['mobile_name'];?></p>
<p>Price:<?php echo $by_name['price'];?></p>
```

Comment: how to show this in the view..? as how i am showing, it is showing data through id but not through the name..?

Comment: To use in view, you will need

Answer (score 0):

So, If I get you correctly and Adding to j.Litvak's code, you want to search the db for a name rather than an id? If so you would need to pass the controller method the name variable i.e. http://localhost/controller_name/method/search_parameter, in your case localhost/controller/selectquery/samsung

Your controller will be

```
public function selectquery($id){
$this->load->database();
$this->load->model('aboutmodel');
$data['h'] = $this->aboutmodel->selectByName($id);
$this->load->view('aboutpageview', $data);
```

}

And Model

```
public function selectByName($name){
$query =$this->db->get_where('phone_mobileinfos',array('name'=>$name));
return $query->result_array();
```

}

And View

`foreach($h as $key => $value){` The code here is obviously in php tags but I cant show them

Mobile: `echo $value['mobile_name'];`

Price: `echo $value['price'];`

`}`

So you create a loop through the result, iterating each result found. 
CAVEAT: you will need to test for a NULL result or you will get an error and be careful passing strings through the URL, codeigniter has sql injection protection but I always like to be safe